# When running DeepSpeech training on Windows, I encountered an error with multiple processes accessing one memory at the same time

Tags: mozilla-deepspeech

Running on pycharm yielded the following error，what should I do?
The following is the error message:

Windows fatal exception: access violation

Thread 0x000013c0 (most recent call first):
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\threading.py", line 295 in wait
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 724 in next
File "E:\pythonProject3\DeepSpeech-0.9.3\training\deepspeech_training\util\helpers.py", line 128 in imap
File "E:\pythonProject3\DeepSpeech-0.9.3\training\deepspeech_training\util\augmentations.py", line 227 in apply_sample_augmentations
File "E:\pythonProject3\DeepSpeech-0.9.3\training\deepspeech_training\util\feeding.py", line 114 in generate_values
File "E:\pythonProject3\DeepSpeech-0.9.3\training\deepspeech_training\util\helpers.py", line 157 in do_iterate
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py", line 594 in generator_py_func
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 235 in **call**

Thread 0x0000525c (most recent call first):
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 306 in _recv_bytes
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 250 in recv
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 463 in _handle_results
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\threading.py", line 864 in run
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\threading.py", line 916 in _bootstrap_inner
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\threading.py", line 884 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x000053b0 (most recent call first):
File "E:\pythonProject3\DeepSpeech-0.9.3\training\deepspeech_training\util\helpers.py", line 123 in _limit
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 290 in _guarded_task_generation
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 419 in _handle_tasks
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\threading.py", line 864 in run
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\threading.py", line 916 in _bootstrap_inner
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\threading.py", line 884 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00005288 (most recent call first):
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 406 in _handle_workers
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\threading.py", line 864 in run
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\threading.py", line 916 in _bootstrap_inner
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\threading.py", line 884 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x000038b4 (most recent call first):
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\threading.py", line 295 in wait
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\queue.py", line 164 in get
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\summary\writer\event_file_writer.py", line 159 in run
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\threading.py", line 916 in _bootstrap_inner
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\threading.py", line 884 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x000041e8 (most recent call first):
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\threading.py", line 295 in wait
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\queue.py", line 164 in get
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\summary\writer\event_file_writer.py", line 159 in run
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\threading.py", line 916 in _bootstrap_inner
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\threading.py", line 884 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00001300 (most recent call first):
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\threading.py", line 295 in wait
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\queue.py", line 164 in get
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\summary\writer\event_file_writer.py", line 159 in run
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\threading.py", line 916 in _bootstrap_inner
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\threading.py", line 884 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x0000253c (most recent call first):
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 1443 in _call_tf_sessionrun
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 1350 in _run_fn
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 1365 in _do_call
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 1359 in _do_run
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 1180 in _run
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 956 in run
File "E:\pythonProject3\DeepSpeech-0.9.3\training\deepspeech_training\train.py", line 572 in run_set
File "E:\pythonProject3\DeepSpeech-0.9.3\training\deepspeech_training\train.py", line 607 in train
File "E:\pythonProject3\DeepSpeech-0.9.3\training\deepspeech_training\train.py", line 954 in main
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 250 in _run_main
File "E:\anaconda\envs\DeepSpeech\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 299 in run
File "E:\pythonProject3\DeepSpeech-0.9.3\training\deepspeech_training\train.py", line 982 in run_script
File "E:/pythonProject3/DeepSpeech-0.9.3/DeepSpeech.py", line 12 in

I installed the other environments and imported the data sets correctly

Answer (score 0):

I haven't come across this type of error before, but I don't use `conda` either.

I strongly suggest you use Docker for training - this is explained in the [DeepSpeech PlayBook](https://mozilla.github.io/deepspeech-playbook/).